# Outliers in residuals plots for Anova

Tags: anova, residuals

I've created an Anova model comparing my algorithm and another algorithm. My experiments are 3 clients accessing 3 servers, with 10 Experiments each Algorithm.

I didn't understand how to explain the distribution of my residuals.While my Normal Q-Q Plot looks pretty well distributed closely to the line. The Residuals vs Fitted shows a huge number of outliers and the residuals plot shows a strange result.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

this would suggest that four of your readings/values are exceptional and need attention. You can either adjust them for their "outliers" or introduce four dummy variables each a 0/1 to moderate their effect using regression analysis. These 4 values ( as observed) will defeat your ability to correctly estimate the impact/significance of your design variables. These four values should be investigated as Bacon pointed out ....

To do science is to search for repeated  patterns.
To detect anomalies is to identify values that do not follow repeated patterns.

For whoever knows the ways of Nature will more easily notice her deviations
and, on the other hand, whoever knows her deviations will more accurately
describe her ways.

One learns the rules by observing when the current rules fail.

These four observations are being effected by variables outside of your "knowledge" . While it is good practice to adjust these values it is even better practice to find out what actually "caused" these exceptional values.

Comment: Since my database reads and write were completely random, there existed the possibility of locks(which was an effect I wanted to produce) Therefore these outliers may be caused by this "lock" effect.


Is it correct to say that my variables Clients and my method explain the effects and show, with few outliers a normal distribution. 

and this red bar in the residuals vs fitted explains what?

My test cases weren't very good, before publication I'll retest my algorithm under more controllable conditions.

Comment: your comment confuses me a little. After adjusting the 4 renegade values one could then obtain a set of residuals and test them for normality as usual.

Comment: I have some possible explanations for these outliers.
I want to rerun my tests which may lead to clearer results.

I don't know how to adjust these 4 renegade values.
I don't have quantitative factors so I cannot create a regression?
I didn't knew how to write an analysis about the above graphs for my "homework" because I didn't know how to interpret each graph.

Comment: The adjustment is simple if the estimated residual is e   , set the corrected y to y - e . Do this separately for each of the 4 readings .